# Orientation preserving implies positive Jacobian determinant

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth oriented manifolds. A local diffeomorphism $F:M\to N$ is called orientation preserving if $F_*$ takes oriented bases to oriented bases. How to show that in this case the Jacobian determinant between smooth oriented charts is positive?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(U,x)$ be coordinates on $M$ and $(V,y)$ on $N$.
I am going to answer assuming that by "Jacobian matrix" you mean the jacobian of the map $\Xi =y\circ F\circ x^{-1}:x(U\cap F^{-1}(V))\rightarrow y(V\cap F(U))$, and not $y\circ x^{-1}$.

As you know, $F_*|_p:T_pM\rightarrow T_{F(p)}N$ is orientation preserving. Since $(\partial_{x^1},\dots,\partial_{x^n})$ and $(\partial_{y^1},\dots,\partial_{y^n})$ are oriented basis, $(F_*(\partial_{x^1}),\dots,F_*(\partial_{x^n}))$ is an orient basis of $TN$ at all points $F(p)$. Now recall the relation
$$F_*(\partial_{x^i}|_p)=\sum_{j=1}^n D_i \Xi^j(x(p))\cdot \partial_{y^j}|_{F(p)}$$
It can be obtained using explicit computation: Refer to Lee's section "The differential in coordinates". This means we have two oriented basis of $T_{F(p)}N$ which are related by the matrix $[D_i \Xi^j(x(p))]_{ij}$. Recall the definition of orientation is exactly a member of the quotient space of bases under the equivillence relation of positive $\text{det}$ transition matrices between them, so this matrix aswell has to have positive determinant.